# java.io.FileNotFoundException InputStream Uploaded File

Tags: java, inputstream, vraptor

I've been developing a function that reads an Excel file, and input its data into a database. The Excel file is chosen by a final user in a Input File (HTML). When I click the submit button, the Controller(Java) receives the file name normally, but, when I try to put the Uploaded File into a InputStream to read the File data and work over it, I got the following exception :
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: "File Name" (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)"

I've been working on it  for 3 days, and 'til now, I got no answers for that at Google.

Controller Method Code

```
@Post
public void pegaArquivoMetas(HttpSession session, UploadedFile planilha) throws IOException, BiffException {
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(planilha.getFileName());
    try{
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inp);
    }catch(BiffException  e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JSP Form Code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="${linkTo[MonitorController].pegaArquivoMetas}" >
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <label for="txtArquivo"></label>
            <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" name="planilha" class="form-control" id="txtArquivo" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="btnAtualizar"></label>
            <button type="submit" id="btnAtualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block disabled"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Atualizar</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

I tried to put some more code at Controller, but, I got the error at the same line of "InputStream inp".

If you guys need more information, please, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

A little guessing here, as I did not do much with vraptor, but assuming you are using this interface:
https://github.com/caelum/vraptor/blob/master/vraptor-core/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/vraptor/interceptor/multipart/UploadedFile.java

Then you should use `planilha.getFile()` to directly get the `InputStream`. `getFileName()` only refers to the "simple name" of the uploaded file, on the computer of the uploading person. You should only use that value for displaying purposes.

Comment: Yeah Florian, I was using this interface, and I tried to put the planilha.getFile() into a InputStream, and that was the problem. 

When we're using multipart/form-data, We don't need to create the file in a local directory, cause the file already exists in the memory, and that's what I was tryin' to do....

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, since you do not actually have a File on Disk, but an UploadedFile object. Try using

```
try (InputStream is = planilha.getInputStream()) {
  Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inp);
} catch (BiffException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

as this **should** give you an InputStream to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on.

It wasn't necessary to throw the UploadedFile into the InputStream. It was possible, and needful to put the UploadFile into the workbook object, directly.

So, the Controller code is like:

```
public void pegaArquivoMetas(HttpSession session, UploadedFile planilha) throws IOException, BiffException {
    Workbook wb;
    try{
        wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(planilha.getFile());
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);
        int linhas = sh.getRows();
    }catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

thank you very much, guys !!!

Comment: it is not common to answer your own question if somebody already gave the correct answer. You should instead mark the correct answer as accepted by clicking the grayed-out checkmark next to the answer.